# Android kotlin version

Tags: android, kotlin

Does anyone face below issue? Can somone help on this. Current gradle version 4.4 in dist

Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50-eap-62.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50-eap-62/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50-eap-62.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50-eap-62/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50-eap-62.jar
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50-eap-62/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50-eap-62.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.50-eap-62/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.50-eap-62.jar

Answer (score 24):

I Faced the same problem on **Android Studio version 3.2**, and I changed this:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
```

**in** `build.gradle(Project:"Your Project Name")` File,

**to this:**

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
```

and **Sync now** or **restarted Android Studio**.

Comment: Make it 1.2.61 now for future ref

Comment: Simply update to latest Kotlin version. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I am not sure my answer is correct. But you can try it.
I changed this:

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50-eap-62'`

to this:

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'`

and restarted Android studio.

Comment: where to find this ext.kotlin_version

Comment: @Akashkumar Gradle->build.gradle(Properties) and inside buildscript

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when i update my **Android Studio**. i solved

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

If you used `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'`

than you need to change `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

Answer (score 0):

Recently I too had the same problem after updating my android studio to 3.5.

I tried the following to resolve this issue.

1. Changed kotlin version to 1.3.21 (**ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'**)

   buildscript {

   ```
   ext.lifecycleVersion = '2.2.0-alpha03'

   ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

   repositories {
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
       google()
       maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
       jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
   }
   ```

   }
2. Select File menu -> Invalidate cache / Restart

Then all worked fine for me after synched the project.

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin Gradle plugin version you are using:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50-eap-62'
```

is not available in the repositories/access issues.

You need to use alternative kotlin_version or update in following:

1. Update android studio
2. Upgrade both Gradle and Kotlin to their latest stable versions.
3. File menu -> Invalidate cache  restart android studio